# Delete a record from a table referring to 2 or more columns from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider having 2 tables as follows.

Table 1:

| Unit | SKU number | Active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | Y |
| B | 2 | Y |
| c | 3 | Y |

Table 2:

| Unit | SKU number | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 4 | Apple |
| B | 2 | Mango |
| Y | 5 | Grapes |
| z | 6 | Banana |

I wanted to delete record `B,2,Y` from table 1 by referring to table 2 where values in columns `Unit` and `SKU number` match.

I tried using the following query but it didn't seem to work

```
DELETE FROM table1 
WHERE (Unit, SKU_Number) IN (SELECT Unit, SKU_Number FROM table2);
```

The error was

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','

Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong here or help me rewrite the SQL query to achieve the required objective?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2):

You could use similar logic with exists:

```sql
DELETE
FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2
              WHERE t2.Unit = t1.Unit AND t2.SKU_Number = t1.SKU_Number);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this query, assuming `Unit` of **Table 1** is unique:

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE table1.Unit IN (
  SELECT table1.Unit 
  FROM table1
  LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.Unit = table2.Unit
                AND table1.SKU_Number = table2.SKU_Number
)
```

If unit is not an unique field, simply replace it with whichever field is unique, or with primary key of **Table 1**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner join for delete:

```
DELETE t1
FROM table1  t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.unit=t2.unit and t1.SKU_Number = t2.SKU.Number
```

Comment: JavaScript Snippets don't improve SQL code.